# infinite series containing cos(x/n)

Tags: sequences-and-series

for $n \in \{ 1,2,3,\dots \}$ we have  $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos(\frac{x}{n})}{n}$.  If integrated term by term twice, the resulting series clearly diverges.  Does this mean the original series diverges as well?  This is not a strictly alternating signs series and those have been difficult to prove the convergence/divergence of them.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

For any specific $x$, it is eventually alternating.  Also,$$\frac d{dn}\frac{\cos(x/n)}{n}$$ is eventually negative, so the alternating series test applies, and it converges.